# Swift UICollectionview Horizontal Cell show center position with automatic move based on cell selection

Tags: swift

My scenario, I am Implementing `UICollectionView` with Horizontal scroll menu. Here, I need to show selected cell automatically move to center position. Within cell I have label for menu and I am using `storyboard`.

Below My Code,

```
extension CameraViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Constants.reuseID, for: indexPath) as! cameraModeCollectionViewCell
        cell.cameraMode.text = self.items[indexPath.item]

        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
            cell.cameraMode.textColor =  colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        } else {
            cell.cameraMode.textColor =  colorLiteral(red: 0.8884977698, green: 0.3220310807, blue: 0, alpha: 0.7236373766)
        }
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        let cellWidth = text.size(withAttributes:[.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)]).width + 10.0
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
    }
}
```

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVR7b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to call `scrollToItem(at:at:animated:)` on `collectionView`, i.e.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)")
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true) //here.....
}
```

No need to call `reloadData()` or anything on the `collectionView`.

Comment: Thanks @PGDev. It is moving but some cell not showing center. I think I need to add header and footer?

Comment: The cell will be centered as per the with of the collectionView. Example: selecting 1st/last cell won't move to centre based on the selection.

Comment: if I want to move first and last cell also to center position. what I want to do @PGDev.

Comment: Then what about the empty space that will be left after moving 1st cell to centre?

Comment: Yes. If there is a space that's not a problem for me. But want to move first and last cell also center position. But note I am using dynamic width for cell label.@PGDev

Comment: Is there any solution @PGDev

Comment: Directly, No. You need to do that manually. You can change the contentInset of the collectionView with calculation. By the way why would you need to implement such a thing?

Comment: If I move first and last cell also center user Interface will be more informative for users. So I ma trying to do that but didn't get any solution.@PGDev

Comment: Instead of that, you can change the UI of the selected cells. Example: put a tick on it or put a line under the cell so you can distinguish the selected one.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Btw I am done by using func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        let inset: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.width * 0.5 - 50 * 0.5
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: inset, bottom: 0, right: inset)
    } @PGDev

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   selectedIndex = indexPath
   collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
   collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Great. Its moving but not showing center.@nimesh surani

Comment: @JamKu Because your all Cell are different size so it can not centre.

Comment: All cell same size then you can able to make it center

Comment: I checked few apps that's different size of content length but Its showing center. for example Microsoft Lens app@nimesh surani

Comment: if I maintain Same size of cell, how to achieve that center positio. Please let me know @nimesh surani